# How to PUT data into an array on a server using AlamoFire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I currently need to PUT data a user inputs into a online server array (see "memberDetails"):

```
{
  "firstName": "Stringy",
  "id": 322344,
"memberDetails": [{
    "city": "asdf",
    "country": "asdf",
    "county": "asdf",
  }],
]
```

I can update everything outside the array just fine but I don't know how to update the items inside the array.  Here is my function for updating the api (note: I use a separate function to update the other data, this is strictly for whats located in the "memberDetailsArray"):

```
func putMemberDetails (accessToken: String, id: Int, city: String, address: String, state: String) {


  //currently test parameters
  let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "id" : id,
    "city" : city,
    "addressLineOne" : address,
    "stateOrProvince" : state,
    ]

  Alamofire.request(.PUT, "\(baseApiUrl)members/updatechildren", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: getHeaders())
    .responseJSON { response in
      print("\(response)")

      if((response.result.value) != nil) {

        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)

        print("This is the updateChildren response:\(swiftyJsonVar)")
      }
  }
}
```

I get a successful response when this function is used, but the data is not changed.

Comment: Your server array seems to be incorrect, can you please copy the exact json data you want to put on the server. Your current json is uncorrect.